# Woocommerce Rest API hosted on Google Cloud Server

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-cloud-platform, woocommerce-rest-api

I've added the key and secret but it's impossible to view the API endpoint for WooCommerce site that hosted on Google Cloud Server.

I have also tried sending a basic request through Postman as suggested in the guide here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Getting-started-with-the-REST-API#making-a-basic-request

It looks like there might be some additional protection enabled on Google Cloud Sevices. The server still doesn't allow me to get through with the key and secret even I removed all plugins and also reinstall WordPress site.

Testing URL: https://staging.tfo.com.au/wc-api/v3/products

Consumer key: ck_cc1ba53ba6b763871679ed2433f5c806c5f9cf4f

Consumer secret: cs_8649198de74ed143a55aff65eead0fc4806220b7

Can anyone help me, please?

Sam,
Thanks

Comment: It has htpassword protected. Have you ostman tried after removing it?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman, I've tried many time but always failed. https://www.screencast.com/t/qPlf4aqUL3D

Comment: Remove htaccess protection and try

Comment: try a product update - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663173/post-update-json-data-in-woocommerce-from-external-api/54663253#54663253

Comment: @MujeebuRahman how can I remove the protection because i used the basic from wordpress. # BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress

Comment: Anything is there in your htaccess like "AuthType"

Comment: @MujeebuRahman there is nothing in the htaccess file. And i also cloned it and uploaded to another then everything is working fine except Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: It's asking for http authentication when accessing